# Laravel route dynamic routes controller to blade template

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-4, laravel-blade

How do I make the controller display in my blade layouts?

I have 250 dynamic routes imported from MySQL. They are produced using the following controller.

```php
public function registerTuningRoutes()
{
   // $tunings = Tuning::all(); // Assume that you have a model Tuning

    // Or you may use this instead
    $tunings = DB::table('guitar_tunings_links')->get();

    // Now loop all tunings and declare routes
    foreach($tunings as $tuning)
    {
        $url = '/tuning/' . $tuning->tuning;
        $route_name = 'tuning.' . $tuning->tuning;
        Route::any($url, $route_name); // You may use get/post
    }
}

public function TuningMethod($tuning = null)
{
    // $tuning will contain the current tuning name, check
    $tuning_name = ($tuning);
    $tuning_name = strtoupper($tuning_name);
    $user = DB::table('guitar_tunings_links')->where('tuning', $tuning_name)->first();

    echo "<div class=\"panel panel-default\">
      <div class=\"panel-heading\">$user->name - $tuning_name</div>
      <div class=\"panel-body\">
        $user->description
      </div>
    </div>";

}
```

Here are my routes...

```php
Route::any('{field}', 'TuningController@TuningMethod');

App::make('TuningController')->registerTuningRoutes();
```

This controller and routing gives me URLs like this
`laravel.dev/eadgbe` which also returns all of the data about the guitar tuning, but it is not residing in my templating system. No styles or layouts are being used.

I have a blade template here app/views/home/tuning.blade.php

My controller works great. It takes the name of the Guitar Tuning from the DB and creates a route from it and prints out the required data from that row.

My problem is I cannot get the output of the controller and the routes to become part of the tuning.blade.php template.

I have tried adding these following routes

```php
// Route 1
Route::get('tuning/{field}', function(){
    return View::make('home.tuning.{field}')
});

// Route 2
Route::get('tuning/{field}', function(){
    return View::make('home.{field}')
});
```

I have read extensively about routing controllers on the Laravel docs section, but I feel I am not understanding it or I am missing something simple.

Also I found this article on advance routing http://daylerees.com/codebright/advanced-routing and have tried to understand and implement it to no avail.

Can anyone help me understand how to to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really have to register all your routes the way you're doing because they can be resolved as only one route. This command was doing nothing, as far as I can tell:

```php
Route::any($url, $route_name);
```

Because it's not pointing to a controller, it's just pointing to a name `tuning.something`, which is nothing to the Laravel router system. So, in fact your whole `registerTuningRoutes` function was doing nothing. But you already had a working route, which was doing all the work for:

```
Route::any('{field}', 'TuningController@TuningMethod');
```

That being said, looks like you can cut some of your code and just have keep this route:

```php
Route::any('{field}', 'TuningController@TuningMethod');
```

Your controller method which is already working but would have to change to render the view directly:

```php
<?php

public function TuningMethod($tuning = null)
{
    // $tuning will contain the current tuning name, check
    $tuning_name = ($tuning);
    $tuning_name = strtoupper($tuning_name);
    $user = DB::table('guitar_tunings_links')->where('tuning', $tuning_name)->first();

    return View::make('home.tuning')->with('user', $user)->with('tuning_name', $tuning_name);
}
```

The `app/views/home/tuning.blade.php` file could be something like:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    <div>
        You HTML here to beautifully render your page.

        This is your tunning details:
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">$user->name - $tuning_name</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                $user->description
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

And you should have a `app/views/layout.blade.php` file, to wrap it all with a HTML and body tags:

```
<html>
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Spot on Antonio! Thank you so very much. I am new to Laravel and I am amazed at how much can be generated with such a small amount of code!

Answer (score 1):

I saw what you tried in the last part of your code (producing dynamic routes). I was really excited to test it on my side and tried to have the same routes but it did not work. I made the following changes to get it working. I hope these changes would be of any help.

P.S. Please pardon me if I got your question wrongly.

```
// Routes.php
Route::get('testCall/{testVariable}', array(
    'as' => 'test', // This is the name of your route
   'uses' => 'Parekhchintan30\Test\TestController@testFunction'
 )); 
// TestController.php
public function testFunction($testVariable){
return View::make('test::'.$testVariable); // obviously you will need a view with that name
}//test is the name of my package in this case
```